# How to unit test xml based dozer mappings

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, dozer

I have a system where mapping of backend to frontend objects (DTOs) is mainly done by applying Dozer mappings selectively. Those mappings are configured via XML.

The code looks like this:

```
        scope2hits.get(scope)
              .add(getMapper().map(srcElement, TargetElement.class));
```

"Unfortunately" I wrote unit tests for the class containing the above code and since getMapper() returns a mocked (Mockito) Mapper, the resulting element is `null`. This is okay for testing amounts but not identity of returned elements.

Is there a way to unit test the class without building the complete context (including not copying the xml files to *test* context)?